# Repository Inheritance

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to create a repository which performs the basic CRUD operations.

Since I have different kind of photos (CompanyPhoto, CarPhoto, ..), I would prefer to make the JPA repository generic, but also the EJB service as well.

Here is my classes:

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DESCRIMINATOR")
    @Table(name = "PHOTOS")
    public abstract class Photo {
        public Photo() {
        }

        public Photo(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
    //      this.file = file;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "PHOTOS_SEQ")
        @TableGenerator(name = "PHOTOS_SEQ", table = "SEQUENCE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", pkColumnValue = "PHOTOS_SEQ", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", allocationSize = 50)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private long id;

        @Column(length = 255)
        @Size(min = 0, max = 255, message = "{Photo.description.size}")
        protected String description;

        @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
        @NotNull(message = "{Photo.fileName.notNull}")
        @Size(min = 1, max = 255, message = "{Photo.fileName.size}")
        protected String fileName;

        // ...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class CarPhoto extends Photo {

    public CarPhoto() {

    }

    public CarPhoto(String fileName) {
        super.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "CARID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Car car;
        // ...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class PersonPhoto extends Photo {

    public PersonPhoto() {

    }

    public PersonPhoto(String fileName) {
        super.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSONID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Person person;
        // ...

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PhotoRepository<E> {

        // In this class I would like to do create, remove, update and some basic find       //operations..


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public PhotoRepository() {
    }

    PhotoRepository(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public E create(E photo) {
        em.persist(photo);
        return photo;
    }

    @Override
    public E modify(E photo)
    {
        Class<E> photoClass;
                // QUESTION: How am I going to call the getId() method from the object of type E  class?
        em.find(photoClass, photo.getId()); // This will not work.. =(
        E mergedPhoto = em.merge(photo);
        return mergedPhoto;
    }
        // ...
```

I hope that you understand what I want to perform. A generic repository for different kind of classes which all inherit from the same baseclass. Can you give me some best practices examples?
 =)

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the generics definition to say that E has to be any type that extends from Photo. Then you will be able to access methods of the Photo class on variables of type E

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PhotoRepository<E extends Photo> {
```

You can use the following method to retrieve the actual class.

```
public Class getEntityClass() {
  ParameterizedType parameterizedType =
    (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperClass();
 return (Class) parameterizedtype.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Ir you are using spring you should also take a look at spring-data-jpa - it provides such generic repositories implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Id from an Entity using,

```
entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(object);
```

Although you do not need to call find() before merge(), just call merge(), it will do the find if required.